# Keyboard not showing when textfield is focused on webbrowser component in codename for android

Tags: android, codenameone

i have a problem with the web browser component for android on codename one. I have loaded a webpage from my php server and it renders well in the web browser component but when i select an input field on a form it doesn't show the keyboard. Any help?

Comment: How do i show keypad when form field is selected in form in a web browser component? Can someone pls help me out. Thanks

Comment: it works fine for me, can you post the html page you are trying to render? and on which android version?

Comment: it works fine on Samsung galaxy s3 4.1.2 android version but on s2 and below, it doesn't show the virtual keyboard. Its a page on my server.

Comment: Can't anyone answer? It works well on android ics 4.1.2, but fails on 2.3.6 and below. Please i need help urgently. My project cnt continue without it.

Comment: WebBrowser w = new WebBrowser();
        w.setName("CheckoutWebBrowser");
        Component c = w.getInternal();
        if (c instanceof BrowserComponent) {
            w.setPreferredW(f.getWidth());
            w.setPreferredH(f.getHeight());
            w.setURL(GlobalVariables.getCheckoutUrl());
            findCheckoutScreenContainerArea().addComponent(w);
//            f.revalidate();
//            f.show();
            f.repaint();
        }

Comment: tested this on my nexus one android version 2.3.6 and it works fine, hows your html page looks like? maybe it's in the html page

Comment: Thank you Chen for replying, this the url of the html page that loads in the webbrowser component: http://198.101.255.182/kollect/client/pay/checkout/d1ccdf569a9c1aa05e3d3dbc01033c94. Please test on your device, thanks

Comment: it works fine on my nexus one

Comment: Really? What am i doing wrong? I don't even see the keyboard on the simulator while testing. I have tried everything and different html pages yet no keyboard, do i need to update my codenameone version for netbeans or something?

Comment: are you building the app with the build server? maybe it's something else in your app, did you tried running a simpler use case?

Comment: yes, its with the build server via netbeans plugin. I tried a simpler code and it still gives the same issue. Maybe because it works well on 4.1.2 version

Comment: can you send me your simple code implementation zip you used to test the url so i can import and build to test. Thanks. My email is klipsedeville@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

If element is focused during response of an ajax call, keypad is not shown in android and iphone.

for example during button click, function onFocus is called.
function onFocus()
{
    1 // Ajax call is made
        2 // if(response)
      element is focused.
}